# How to show that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega:=[0,1]$ and $\mathcal F :=\{ A \subseteq [0,1] \,|\, A\,\, is \,\, countable\,\, or \,\, A^c\,\, is \,\, countable\}.$ How can I show that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @UserUser you can show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra by showing that it is closed under complements, countable unions, and showing that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$, since $\emptyset= \Omega^c$ is countable.
2. Let $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B=A^c$. If $A$ is countable, then $B^c$ is countable, hence  $B \in \mathcal{F}$ . If $A^c$ is countable, then also  $B \in \mathcal{F}$.
3. Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ and $U=\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N}A_j$. If all $A_j$ are countable, then $U$ is countable, and therefore $U \in \mathcal{F}$. If there is $j$ such that $A_j$ is not countable, then $A_j^c$  is countable. From $U^c \subseteq A_j^c$ we get that $U^c$ is countable and therefore $U \in \mathcal{F}$